# What is SubSonic's license?

Tags: open-source, subsonic, licensing, subsonic3

I've looked all over the SubSonic website, but I can't find anything about its licensing.  With the project I am working on, I need to list all the open source projects I use along with their licenses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our license is New BSD with a the Linq core bits covered under MS-PL (matt warren's linq code)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the source tree](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/master/SubSonic.Core/LICENSE.txt) it's new BSD.

but best is to talk to the devs and ask them to make the license clearer to mkae sure other users know their rights, too.